# It this the correct way of implement "gather and go" in Python multiple threading? And how do you call it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm implementing a "gather and go" feature. I need a batch of threads to work simultaneously. It may take a while for each threading to prepare and then become ready. I want them to start at the same time once all of them are ready.

Event object in threading module can be used for it. For example I can create an event in main thread, then wait() for it in the worker threads, then set() the event in main thread. But how can I know from main thread that all worker threads are ready? Should I use event either? For example create an event for each worker thread?

Code example

```
from threading import Thread, Event, Lock, current_thread
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from random import random

log_lock = Lock()


def log(msg):
    with log_lock:
        print("{} ({}) {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), current_thread().name, msg))


def worker(worker_ready_event, go_event):
    log("Initializing worker")
    sleep(2 + random() * 3)
    worker_ready_event.set()
    log("Worker is ready")
    go_event.wait()
    log("Worker is working")
    log("Worker has finished their work")


def main():
    go_event = Event()
    event_list = list()
    for i in range(1, 6):
        worker_ready_event = Event()
        event_list.append(worker_ready_event)
        Thread(name=f"Worker-{i}", target=worker, args=(worker_ready_event, go_event)).start()

    for worker_ready_event in event_list:
        worker_ready_event.wait()
    log("All workers are ready, Go!")
    go_event.set()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is the above code the correct way of implement it? Or is there any exiting tool for this "gather and go"? And one more question: how to you call this scenario? "Gather and go", or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`threading.Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Barrier) is built for this. Initialize it with the number of threads that you want to synchronize. Each thread calls `wait` which will wait until all threads have done the same. That final `wait` releases all of them to run at once.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread, Barrier
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from random import random

log_lock = Lock()


def log(msg):
    with log_lock:
        print("{} ({}) {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), current_thread().name, msg))


def worker(barrier):
    log("Initializing worker")
    sleep(2 + random() * 3)
    log("Worker is ready")
    barrier.wait()
    log("Worker is working")
    sleep(.1)
    log("Worker has finished their work")


def main():
    num_threads = 5
    work_barrier = Barrier(num_threads+1)
    for i in range(1, num_threads+1):
        Thread(name=f"Worker-{i}", target=worker, args=(work_barrier,)).start()
    log("main waits")
    work_barrier.wait() # waits til all workers are ready
    log("All workers are ready") # this thread starts w/ the workers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```